# SceneKit LIDAR iOS: Show unscanned regions of camera view in the background with a different color/texture

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit, lidar

I'm building an app similar to Polycam, 3D Scanner App, Scaniverse, etc. I visualize a mesh for scanned regions and export it into different formats. I would like to show the user what regions are scanned, and what not. To do so, I need to differentiate between them.

My idea is to build something like Polycam does..
[< Polycam blue background for unscanned regions >](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0nkB.png)

I tried changing the background content property of the scene, but it causes the whole camera view to be replaced by the color.

```
arSceneView.scene.background.contents = UIColor.black
```

I'm using ARSCNView and setting up plane detection as follows:

```
private func setupPlaneDetection() {
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        configuration.sceneReconstruction = .meshWithClassification
        configuration.frameSemantics = .smoothedSceneDepth
        
        arSceneView.session.run(configuration)
        arSceneView.session.delegate = self
       // arSceneView.scene.background.contents = UIColor.black
        arSceneView.delegate = self
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
        
        arSceneView.showsStatistics = true
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I’ve done this before by adding a sphere to the scene with a two-sided material (slightly transparent) and with a radius large enough that the camera and the scanned surface will always be inside of it. Here’s an example of how to do that:

```
let backgroundSphereNode = SCNNode() 
backgroundSphereNode.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 500)

let material = SCNMaterial()
material.isDoubleSided = true
material?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.9)
backgroundSphereNode.geometry?.materials = [material]
```

Note that I’m using a black color - you can obviously change this to whatever you need, but keep the alpha channel slightly transparent. And tweak the radius of the sphere so it works for your scene.

Comment: This allowed me to add a static translucent background to the scene. That was helpful. However I need to replace the successfully scanned regions with the actual scene colors and textures. Or in other words, remove the background from already scanned regions. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Additionaly, the exported model is hidden due to this bit of code and I unfortunately couldn't figure out how to work with this. But,thanks for your help!